# mysql join rows with from only 1 id

Tags: mysql, join

I am attempting to query two tables to create a monthly employee time  report. When I join the tables using INNER JOIN (emp_nr is the same in both tables) then I get the following. Please excuse me if I have not the correct formatting.

Table employee

```
id | emp_nr | name | vorname | address | city .....bla bla bla
```

Table zeit (szeit and ezeit are datetime Y-m-d H:i:s)

```
id | emp_nr | szeit | ezeit |
```

my query

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"
SELECT e.vorname
     , e.name
     , e.emp_nr
     , a.szeit
     , a.ezeit
  FROM employee e
  JOIN zeit a
 WHERE a.szeit BETWEEN '$jahr-$monat-01' AND '$jahr-$monat-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND e.emp_nr = 57
 ORDER 
    BY e.emp_nr
     , a.szeit
");
```

my results are the following:  Here I get all rows of all employees with the name and emp_nr from only one

```
Juli    Zimmerm 57  2018-02-01 09:45:37 2018-02-01 14:15:08
Juli    Zimmerm 57  2018-02-01 18:00:00 2018-02-01 22:30:00
Juli    Zimmerm 57  2018-02-01 19:33:00 2018-02-01 19:44:00
Juli    Zimmerm 57  2018-02-02 10:31:25 2018-02-02 14:30:25
```

In the code when I change
    ON e.emp_nr = 57
to
    ON a.emp_nr = 57
I get the following results.

Everyone listed individually but all the times are the same and the requested emp_nr is not there.

```
Frank   Cas 01  2018-02-01 19:33:00 2018-02-01 19:44:00
Julie   Cas 03  2018-02-01 19:33:00 2018-02-01 19:44:00
Lisa    Ket 15  2018-02-01 19:33:00 2018-02-01 19:44:00
Anja    Fis 22  2018-02-01 19:33:00 2018-02-01 19:44:00
```

What I am trying to get is a report where only the correct ID
with the correct name comes out.

for the simplest SELECT

```
SELECT emp_nr, szeit, ezeit 
FROM zeit 
WHERE szeit BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-01' + 
    INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND emp_nr = 57
```

The result is without the corresponding name from table employee

```
57 2018-02-01 19:33:00 2018-02-01 19:44:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `JOINS` you need to specify the relationship between the 2 tables using `ON` clause

```
SELECT e.vorname, e.name, e.emp_nr, a.szeit, a.ezeit
FROM zeit a 
JOIN employee e ON a.emp_nr = e.emp_nr
WHERE a.szeit BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-01' + 
INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND e.emp_nr = 57
ORDER BY e.emp_nr, a.szeit
```

Comment: Would appreciate a thumbs up and an acceptance to my answer.

Comment: new to Stackoverflow, give me the howto for a thumbs up